# How do I get an image into an Object[] in Java?

Tags: java, html, css, image, swing

Hello I'm trying to place an image as a bullet point type of thing in a JOptionPane. What is displayed in the JOptionPane I've put in side an object array. But it just doesn't take the image. it shows me the file name though...
Any ideas?

```
public void popups(){

    ImageIcon bullet = new ImageIcon("imgs/bullet.png");

    Object[] instr = {+bullet+ "text "};

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, instr, "Instrucciones", 1);        
}
```

EDIT:

```
StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
    html.append("<html><ul> list-style-image: url ('imgs/bullet.png')</ul>"
            + "<ul>"
            + "<li>TEXT"
            + "<li>TEXT"
            + "</ul></html>");

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, html, "Instrucciones", 1);
```

[image: POPUP example]

Comment: Do you want to show a bullet in the message string of the MessageDialog? Or you want to show a custom image as the Icon of the dialog?

Comment: its a custom image i called bullet.png i want it to show every time i call it in the array

Comment: Can you illustrate what you want to show?

Answer (score 2):

Provide a style specifying the image.

```css
ul {
    list-style-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJmeJ.png');
}
```

Then the effect of this:

```html
<ul>
<li>This is a list point.
<li>This is a 2nd list point.
</ul>
```

Is this:

[image]

Note: That image was generated using a Swing based `JLabel`. Swing's support for CSS is quite limited / patchy, so always best to check.

Comment: that's html how would i incorporate it? i opened the <html></html> but it gives me error inside the object[] and outside in the method

Comment: [edit] the question to show a [mcve] of your attempt.

Comment: i tried it with a string builder but... it shows me the text inside the url and black bullet points instead of the image

Comment: is that what you need?

Comment: What part of the linked document are you having trouble understanding? Here is a more complete description of the same thing: [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).